# How to refresh DialogFragment after dismiss of another DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, dialogfragment

I have an `AppCompatActivity` that, at some point, display a `DialogFragment`. In this dialog, there are items for which I ask confirmation before deleting them. That confirmation is asked through another Yes/No `DialogFragment`. When the user clicks Yes in that second dialog, I want the first dialog to refresh its `ListView` (just need to update the adapter and call its `notifyDataSetChanged` method). The problem is that I don't know when to update the listview.

Because that delete functionality is called from various sources, I implement a listener Interface at the activity level and call an "onDeleteRequest" event from that interface whenever I need an item to be deleted, and that's the activity who opens up the confirmation dialog and perform the actual delete.

Since I don't care much about refreshing the ListView in unnecessary situations, I tried to update the list in the `onResume` event, but the event is not called when I come back to the first dialog after the confirmation one is dismissed.

So my question is: how can I know when a dialog B displayed on top of a dialog A has been dismissed so I can refresh dialog A accordingly?

**EDIT : A bit of code to support my question:**

My activity class:

```
public class MonthActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnEditCalendarsDialogListener
{
    ...

    //That's where dialog A is shown
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        ...

        if (id == R.id.action_select_calendar) {
            final CalendarSelection currentSelection = mCalendarSelectionAdapter.getCurrentCalendarSelection();

            if (currentSelection != null) {
                EditCalendarsDialogFragment dialogFragment = EditCalendarsDialogFragment.newInstance(currentSelection);
                dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    ...

    //OnEditCalendarsDialogListener interface implementation

    //That's where Dialog B is shown over Dialog A
    @Override
    public void onEditCalendarsDialogDelete(long calendarID) {
        final Repository repository = Repository.getInstance(this);
        final Calendar calendar = repository.fetchOneByID(Calendar.class, calendarID);

        if (calendar != null) {
            YesNoDialog yesNoDialog = YesNoDialog.newInstance(this, R.string.yes_no_dialog_confirmation, R.string.yes_no_dialog_calendar_delete);
            setCurrentOnDecisionClickListener(new OnPositiveClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPositiveClick(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    //Delete calendar
                    repository.delete(calendar);
                    //That's where I'd like to notify Dialog A that it needs to be refreshed
                    return true;
                }
            });
            yesNoDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
    }
}
```

My dialog class

```
public class EditCalendarsDialogFragment
        extends DialogFragment
{
    private OnEditCalendarsDialogListener mDialogListener;

    public static EditCalendarsDialogFragment newInstance(CalendarSelection calendarSelection) {
        EditCalendarsDialogFragment dialog = new EditCalendarsDialogFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

        if (calendarSelection != null) {
            arguments.putLong(KEY_ID, calendarSelection.getID());
        }
        else {
            arguments.putLong(KEY_ID, 0L);
        }

        dialog.setArguments(arguments);

        return dialog;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mDialogListener = (OnEditCalendarsDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCalendarSelectionDialogListener");
        }
    }

    ...

    private View getLayoutView() {
        View rootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.calendar_list, null, false);

        if (rootView != null) {
            mCalendars = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendars);
            if (mCalendars != null) {
                //Create adaptor
                mCalendarAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Calendar>(
                        getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                        android.R.id.text1,
                        new ArrayList<Calendar>()
                ) {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                        final Calendar calendar = getItem(position);

                        if (calendar != null && calendar.hasID()) {
                            ...
                            view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                                    if (mDialogListener != null) {
                                        //That's where I request delete from calling activity
                                        mDialogListener.onEditCalendarsDialogDelete(calendar.getID());
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        return view;
                    }
                };
                mCalendars.setAdapter(mCalendarAdapter);
                refreshCalendarList();
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally used the "over-abusive-callback" method.

I created the following interface:

```
public interface OnDeletedListener {
    void onDeleted();
}
```

Updated the OnEditCalendarsDialogListener interface so that the callback has a callback to this interface too:

```
public interface OnEditCalendarsDialogListener {
    void onEditCalendarsDialogDelete(long calendarID, OnDeletedListener onDeletedListener);
}
```

Implemented the OnDeletedListener interface in "Dialog A" class:

```
public class EditCalendarsDialogFragment
        extends DialogFragment
        implements OnDeletedListener
{
    ...

    //OnDeletedListener interface implementation

    @Override
    public void onDeleted() {
        //That's where I'm called back after item is deleted
        refreshCalendarList();
    }

    ...

    private View getLayoutView() {
        ...
        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (mDialogListener != null) {
                    //That's where I request delete from calling activity, asking to call me back once deleted
                    mDialogListener.onEditCalendarsDialogDelete(calendar.getID(), EditCalendarsDialogFragment.this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

And finally, call the callback when delete is accepted and performed:

```
public class MonthActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnEditCalendarsDialogListener
{
    //OnEditCalendarsDialogListener interface implementation

    //That's where Dialog B is shown over Dialog A
    @Override
    public void onEditCalendarsDialogDelete(long calendarID, final OnDeletedListener onDeletedListener) {
        final Repository repository = Repository.getInstance(this);
        final Calendar calendar = repository.fetchOneByID(Calendar.class, calendarID);

        if (calendar != null) {
            YesNoDialog yesNoDialog = YesNoDialog.newInstance(this, R.string.yes_no_dialog_confirmation, R.string.yes_no_dialog_calendar_delete);
            setCurrentOnDecisionClickListener(new OnPositiveClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPositiveClick(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    //Delete calendar
                    repository.delete(calendar);
                    //That's where I notify Dialog A that it needs to be refreshed
                    if (onDeletedListener != null) {
                        onDeletedListener.onDeleted();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            yesNoDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
    }
}
```

Works smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Register your dialog A to listen to events. When you dismiss dialog B post an event and pass the listitem's adapter position or whatever data you want to use to identify which item is to be deleted. Inside your dialog A write a function to receive this event inside which you delete the item.

Comment: Since it's for a school assignment, I was looking for a solution not involving a third party library. But for future projects, that implementation of the Publish-Suscriber design pattern might prove useful. I kept it in my bookmarks for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: There are other ways also, like the interface one u said. Or while opening the dialog b you can pass a reference of dialog a and call your deleteitem method of dialog a from dialog b when u delete an item and dismiss it. But remember to check if dialog a's instance is not null before calling the method to avoid NPE.